# How to convert port to string and list in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I convert all chars of a port to a string or a list so that I can operate on it as either a list of chars or a string?

I was wondering if something similar to

```
(define (port->list port) (list port))
```

is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket provides a built-in [`port->string`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html?q=port-%3Estring#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._port-~3estring%29%29) function. If you want, you can subsequently call [`string->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string-%3Elist#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-~3elist%29%29) on the resulting string to get a list of characters.

Of course, if you wanted to do it in one step, defining such a function would be trivial:

```
(define (port->list port)
  (string->list (port->string port)))
```

Comment: so something like (define (port->list port) (string->list (port->string port)))?

Comment: @user2175783 Yes, I added an example of that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Racket provides comprehensions, which really should be the thing to use.

```
(define (port->list port)
  (for/list ((c (in-port read-char port))) c))
```

In so saying, Racket already provides its own `port->list` and your version would actually conflict with it.